# SQL update query with subquery search condition

Tags: sql

I have a homework question where we need to write an `UPDATE` statement to change category name of Categories in Ass7 by removing its last two characters if the category's products in dbo schema has an average unit price above $30.
Ass7 is a Schema we made of a database that has the relevant tables Categories and Products. the Categories table has the Category Name and the Products table has unit prices, with each product having a category ID. I was trying something like this

```
UPDATE Ass7.Categories
SET CategoryName = LEFT(CategoryName, (LEN(CategoryName) - 2))
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT CategoryID
            ,AVG(UnitPrice) AS average
        FROM Ass7.Categories
        INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON Ass7.Categories.CategoryID = dbo.Products.CategoryID
        WHERE average > 30
        GROUP BY Ass7.Categories.CategoryID
        );
```

But I'm a but confused as to where to go.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I may need to use a HAVING clause instead of a subquery like I'm doing but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: can you replicate your problem with http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? if you can, please edit your question add the link to your problem

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over-complicating the query. you just need a sub-query which return `category_id` of products `having avg(unit_price) > 30` as below.

```
UPDATE Ass7.Categories
SET CategoryName = LEFT(CategoryName, (LEN(CategoryName) - 2))
WHERE CategoryID IN(
        SELECT p.CategoryID
        FROM dbo.Products p
        GROUP BY p.CategoryID
        having AVG(p.UnitPrice) > 30
        );
```